# Forms authentication and server time

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a server that gets it time reset to 7 hours in the past.  When this happens forms authentication no longer works.

When I resync the time with the server time it works again.

What could be causing this?  It is actually and issue for me more so then changing the time, because I don't think it will be possible to keep all the clients and the servers in sync.

Comment: This is not normal behavior, the server time should stay in sync with real time. Having incorrect time or even worse date causes many undesirable side effects which I have come across countless of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a production server with jumping time.  Google "Windows NTP time synchronization" to find how to easily configure your servers to always be within microseconds of correct time.